# Performance problems with two left joins. Is there an alternative with unpivot?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]    INT              DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]   INT              DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [LastName]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Here's a report that I run on the data and below that is the output I want:

```
SELECT   u.LastName
        ,COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pc.PhraseId),0) AS CreatedByQty
        ,COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pm.PhraseId),0) AS ModifiedByQty
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers u
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pc
        ON u.Id = pc.CreatedBy
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pm
        ON u.Id = pm.ModifiedBy
GROUP BY u.LastName


LastName   CreatedByQty  ModifiedQty

ad1        100           50
ad2        10             5
ad3        200           99
```

However the performance is terrible.  It's now taking over 1 minute to run even though the number of rows in Phrase is only 5,000. Note that there are more columns in Phrase but I missed these out as they are not referenced.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to an alternative way that I could get this data.  I was hoping to use unpivot but not sure how to use it for this situation.

Does anyone thing an index on PhraseId, CreatedBy and ModifiedBy would help. Would it use this index rather than going to Phrase for the data?

Comment: Have a look into execution plan. Locate most expensive operation(s). Probably your database missing some indexes.

Comment: FirstName and LastName are `NVARCHAR(MAX)`? Really?? Correct the datatypes, create indexes for join columns and maybe the order column, and this should fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't already have these indexes, I would add them:

```
create nonclustered index ix_Phrase_CreatedBy on dbo.Phrase (CreatedBy)
create nonclustered index ix_Phrase_ModifiedBy on dbo.Phrase (ModifiedBy)
```

You also shouldn't need to use `count(distinct ...)` since `PhraseId` is unique, or `coalesce()`:

rextester: http://rextester.com/CMP5250

```
select
    u.LastName
  , CreatedByQty =count(pc.CreatedBy)
  , ModifiedByQty=count(pm.ModifiedBy)
from dbo.AspNetUsers u
  left join dbo.Phrase pc
    on u.Id = pc.CreatedBy
  left join dbo.Phrase pm
    on u.Id = pm.ModifiedBy
group by u.LastName
```

Comment: Added those and execution time within a few seconds of before so I don't think there's any change.

Comment: Your second suggestion made it run five times faster. Do you think any other index might help?

Comment: @Anne The only other index I can see being used would be on `LastName`: `create nonclustered index ix_AspNetUsers_LastName on dbo.AspNetUsers (LastName)`