# How can I combine two queries horizontally?

Tags: sql-server

I coded the following query:

```
SELECT u.LastName Col1
, convert(varchar, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pm.PhraseId), 0)) AS Col2
, convert(varchar, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pc.PhraseId), 0)) AS Col3
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers u
LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pm ON u.Id = pm.ModifiedBy
LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pc ON u.Id = pc.CreatedBy
GROUP BY u.LastName
```

Performance was extremely bad and it took over a minute to run.

I then tried breaking it down into two queries and each of these take just two seconds to run:

```
SELECT u.LastName Col1
, convert(varchar, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pm.PhraseId), 0)) AS Col2
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers u
LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pm ON u.Id = pm.ModifiedBy
GROUP BY u.LastName

SELECT u.LastName Col1
, convert(varchar, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pc.PhraseId), 0)) AS Col2
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers
LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pm ON u.Id = pc.CreatedBy
GROUP BY u.LastName
```

As the first query is not runnable I would like to find some way to combine the outputs of the two smaller queries. 
Here's the result I would like to get along with the table DDL:

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]    INT              DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]   INT              DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [LastName]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Col1       Col2        Col3

ad1        100           50
ad2        10             5
ad3        200           99
```

Note that I have indexed like this:

```
create nonclustered index ix_Phrase_CreatedBy on dbo.Phrase (CreatedBy)
create nonclustered index ix_Phrase_ModifiedBy on dbo.Phrase (ModifiedBy)
```

I'd appreciate suggestions on how I could combine the smaller 2 second run time queries as it seems whatever I 
do I cannot get the first query to run fast. Not sure if this is a SQL Server issue or what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

As I mentioned here: [Performance problems with two left joins. Is there an alternative with unpivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205613/performance-problems-with-two-left-joins-is-there-an-alternative-with-unpivot)

You also should not need to use `count(distinct ...)` since `PhraseId` is unique, or `coalesce()`:

rextester: http://rextester.com/CMP5250

```
select
    u.LastName
  , CreatedByQty =count(pc.CreatedBy)
  , ModifiedByQty=count(pm.ModifiedBy)
from dbo.AspNetUsers u
  left join dbo.Phrase pc
    on u.Id = pc.CreatedBy
  left join dbo.Phrase pm
    on u.Id = pm.ModifiedBy
group by u.LastName
```

You could also try swapping a left join for `outer apply()` but I do not know if that will help:

```
select
    u.LastName
  , CreatedByQty =count(pc.CreatedBy)
  , ModifiedByQty=pm.ModifiedByQty
from dbo.AspNetUsers u
  left join dbo.Phrase pc
    on u.Id = pc.CreatedBy
outer apply (
    select ModifiedByQty=count(1) 
    from dbo.Phrase pm
    where u.Id = pm.ModifiedBy
    ) pm
group by u.LastName
```